# I have two arrays and a text file and i want it to put a specific word into one array and someting else into the other (VB)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, streamreader

So i have a problem in visual basic, I have two arrays called arrLang1 and arrLang2

i want to put the word before the - into the first array and the word after the - into the second array. And these words come from a txt file.

> SwedishWord1 - EnglishWord1
>
> SwedishWord2 - EnglishWord2
>
> SwedishWord3 - EnglishWord3
>
> SwedishWord4 - EnglishWord4

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [`Dictionary(Of String. String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead? They are especially created for such a requirement.

The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` generic class provides a mapping from a set of **keys** to a set of **values**. Each addition to the dictionary consists of a value and its associated key. Retrieving a value by using its key is **very fast**, close to O(1). Every key must be **unique**.

```
Dim allLines = From line In File.ReadLines(path) Where Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)
Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
For Each line As String In allLines
    Dim words = line.Split({" - "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    If words.Length >= 2 Then
        dict(words(0)) = words(1)
    End If
Next
```

If you insist on a collection i would use a `List(Of String)` instead of an array because you don't know the correct size and arrays are fixed size:

```
Dim swedishWords = New List(Of String)
Dim englishWords = New List(Of String)
For Each line As String In allLines
    Dim words = line.Split({" - "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    If words.Length >= 2 Then
        swedishWords.Add(words(0))
        englishWords.Add(words(1))
    End If
Next
```

If you really need arrays `swedishWords.ToArray()` and `englishWords.ToArray()` afterwards.